# QT Обновление данных в QComboBox из базы данных C++

Tags: c++, sql, база-данных, qt, combobox

На виджете лежит ComboBox с данными из базы. С этого виджета вызываю диалог, в котором делаю еще одну запись в базу. Как сделать, чтобы при этом у меня в ComboBox сразу появилась эта запись, а не после перезапуска программы? Если можно, поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как вариант, после записи в базу запомнить текст combobox,  setModel заново, а потом поиском comboboks'а встать на запись

Comment: а можно пример? я просто не понимаю как диалог этот с виджетом связать

Comment: Подключайтесь к сигналу завершения диалога `void QDialog::finished(int result)` (или посылайте свой сигнал). В обработчике перезаполняйте актуальными значениями `QComboBox`.

Answer (score -1):

```
QComboBox *combobox = new QComboBox; 
fillMyComBoBox(); // новая запись из бд в комбобокс
combobox->update();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.